# When I run "rails s" I get "stack level too deep (SystemStackError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This issue seem to have come about after I tried to deploy this app to heroku

Here's the whole error i get when i run the rail server.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
PrideCoding:autosales elyseemontissol$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:744:in `log_call': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:478:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
     ... 7345 levels...
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/elyseemontissol/autosales/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PrideCoding:autosales elyseemontissol$
```

Comment: By any chance do you have a instance method named same as a model column name?

Comment: I actually fixed, it was something i did when I first got the error, i un-did it and BAM! it works. Thank you for your response and trying to help  @Sahil